# AppDelegate setFullscreen: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to receive RevMobAdsDelegate events in my AppDelegate and they are  being called with following runtime signal errors .

```
[3496:207] [RevMob myapplication App]
SetChartBoostRequestFlag - StopLoadingWait
[3496:207] [RevMob myapplication App] StopLoadingWait routine
[3496:207] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
[3496:207] [RevMob] Initializing Fullscreen.
[3496:207] -[AppDelegate setFullscreen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance    0xa20b4e0
(gdb)
```

i have already added RevModAds Framework in my code still it's giving me this kind of signal error. and application crashed after loading starting banner.

i have installed RevMobads sdk from here
    http://sdk.revmob.com/ios.html#fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  #define REVMOB_APP_ID @"50cd7e844ae728120000003f"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
  {  
            [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:REVMOB_APP_ID];
            [self showAds];
            ..
            ..
  }

  -(void)showAds  //call this from game over, game pause
  {
            [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but still giving error:-[AppDelegate setFullscreen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd00022. on this line of my code >> self.fullscreen = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];

Comment: This is the RevMobAd class for more understanding :  http://sdk.revmob.com/api/ios/Classes/RevMobAds.html

Comment: this one for fullscreen : http://sdk.revmob.com/api/ios/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/fullscreen

Comment: my game starts with initial banner then signal error generated like this :2013-06-18 18:45:17.085 mygame[7382:207] [RevMob mygame App] SetChartBoostRequestFlag - StopLoadingWait
2013-06-18 18:45:17.092 mygame[7382:207] [RevMob mygame App] StopLoadingWait routine
2013-06-18 18:45:17.093 AvalancheMountain[7382:207] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
2013-06-18 18:45:28.348 AvalancheMountain[7382:207] [RevMob] Initializing Fullscreen.
2013-06-18 18:45:28.354 mygame[7382:207] -[AppDelegate setFullscreen:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd000220

Comment: PLEASE HELP : ME STUCK WITH THIS ERROR FROM COUPLE OF DAYS

Comment: thanks for your help .. now  i jus implemnted same as u suggest but now me having this error :-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bc6c50

Comment: this is not rev mob related error. Just comment all revmob code and try

Comment: thnks buddy ..now my game is finally running :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `setFullscreen:` method in your AppDelegate? If not, you better implement it. The documentation says that there is a `showFullscreen`, which is different.

Comment: ya right , i don't have any method named setFullscreen still its calling that method and that is my query.i really don't understand why it's calling that method .